# How to get temperature value from DS18B20 voltage

Tags: controller, arduino, hardware, sensors, temperature

I just connected DS18B20 temperature sensor to ADC of a device. But that device only shows voltage reading from ADC likve 1033 mV. 
But I want to get an actual temperature value from the voltage value.
Is there any way to calculate or get the temperature value from voltage reading?

Please let me know.

Thanks,

Comment: As [the DS18B20 is a 1-Wire device](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS18B20.pdf) that seems quite strange. Are you sure you aren't reading 1-Wire data??? Check [this arduino playground page](http://playground.arduino.cc/Learning/OneWire) the conversion code is just below the 1wire communication code. Why this code does what it does is explained in the datasheet, the first link.

Comment: The DS18B20 is connected to Calmp modem not Arduino. That's why I can't read the data. Because I can't program that modem. Calamp only shows ADC voltage.

Comment: Would the temperature corresponding to 1033 happen to be around 65 Celsius (that's around 150 Fahrenheit)?

Comment: Here the only answer should be "learn to read datasheets"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to connect the 18B20 to a microcontroller, or a 1-wire host controller, connected to the microcontroller.  (The difference is whether you want to write your own 1-wire protocol code ... go with the host controller).  You'll get a digital value for the temp, no ADC required.

Comment: Thank you!! I have thought DS18B20 is an analog sensor and sends its temperature value as analog voltage level to microcontroller.